# Нужна здесь запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение

**"Расскажешь мне потом, на какой станции она расположена?"**

Нужна здесь запятая? Если да, то почему?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая необходима:

> Расскажешь мне потом, на какой станции она расположена.

Дело в том, что это сложное предложение, между частями которого ставится запятая. Первой грамматической основой является «расскажешь», второй — «она расположена».

Answer (score 1):

Расскажешь мне потом, на **какой** станции она расположена.

Это сложноподчиненное предложение с изъяснительным придаточным, союзное слово КАКОЙ относится к падежной форме ***на станции***.

В главном предложении опорное слово ***расскажешь*** со значением речи.